# How to further extract list to make a triple nested list from a double nested list

Tags: scala

I have a list of lists that I want to separate using one of the internal values

I was thinking hash map would work but I am not that familiar with it so a list would look like this

```
val data: List[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = List((0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 7), (2, 1, 5, 5), (3, 1, 3, 7), (4, 1, 2, 8), (5, 1, 5, 4), (6, 1, 3, 5))
```

and I want to get something like:

```
List(((0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 7), (4, 1, 2, 8)), ((3, 1, 3, 7),(6, 1, 3, 5)),((5, 1, 5, 4), (2, 1, 5, 5)))
```

I separate it by the 3rd element in each list

Comment: Your `data` isn't a List of Lists... it's a List of tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution to what you are looking for but you will have List of list not a List of Tuples:

```
val list : List[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = List((0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 7), (2, 1, 5, 5), (3, 1, 3, 7), (4, 1, 2, 8), (5, 1, 5, 4), (6, 1, 3, 5))

 list.groupBy(_._3).values.toList

> res = List(List((0,1,2,3), (1,1,2,7), (4,1,2,8)), List((2,1,5,5), (5,1,5,4)), List((3,1,3,7), (6,1,3,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupBy` function on a list:

```
list.groupBy( i => i._3 )
```

will create a Hashmap. You will want to massage the `values` of the Map afterwards.

Good luck !